# Calculation of the difference of two Brownian bridges

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I was told that the difference of two independent brownian bridge process is $\sqrt{2}$ times a brownian bridge process, i.e.,

$$B_{1t} - B_{2t} = \sqrt{2}B_t$$

where $B_{1t}$ and $B_{2t}$ are independent brownian bridge processes, but I can't seem to see why that is. Can someone validate that it's a true statement? Or is the difference of two brownian bridges something else?

Comment: I answered there https://app.box.com/file/1215555070138 MathStackExchange would be more appropriate for this kind of question.